# How to use UI Pencil “*.ep /*.epz files” to create Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to programing and android, I have just started to  learn android programing.  I have downloaded UI Evolus Pencil. The output generated by Pencil program is *.ep /*.epz

How can I use “*.ep /*.epz  files”  file in my android project to generate layout.

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: Just did a quick skimming from the official web site and I don't think you can export XML layout directly from UI Pencil. I guess it's just a prototyping tool. You have to write the XML by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a prototyping tool.You only can design it. but you can't get the output as a xml file. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kE6vK7XA8YU)